# Windows Phone 7 - buying a developer device

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Where can I buy a Windows Phone 7 developer device?  How much does it cost?

Comment: Where can I buy a device without renewing a cellular phone contract?

Comment: Best thing is to visit any Mobile Phone stores where you live and ask them if they have any non-contract phones. O2 here in the UK offers Pay as you Go phones without a contract (although I had to get a contract) Any Windows Phone 7 device can be used as a developer phone once unlocked with the subscription and tools. You can also check the websites of any phone companies such as AT&T, T-Mobile etc and see what they have there.

Answer (score 8):

You simply buy a normal device and then use the Zune software to associate it with a developer account. That will let you deploy your own applications to it. (You do need to have the developer account though, which I believe costs $99 per year.)

The cost will vary by country, device and operator of course. I bought mine without a contract, which was obviously beneficial as I already have a perfectly good contract :)

Comment: Yes, please inform me where you bought yours without the contract.

Comment: @CalvinS: Given that I'm in the UK and you're in the US, it's probably irrelevant to you I'm afraid.

Comment: yeah, the us phone market can be a total PITA in that regard.  there's always the ebay/craigslist "Grey market" too.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to renew your contract, you could buy an unlocked phone from sites like this one: http://www.expansys-usa.com/s.aspx?sid=27172360&cat=WINPHONE&search=window%20phone%207

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the US, the phones from AT&T listed at http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/buy/7/phones.aspx are available without a contract for $499.99

Comment: 500 simoleons?  Ouch...guess I'll head over to AT&T's refurbished store...may need to wait a while, though...

Comment: That price is comparable with most unlocked smartphones. disappointingly

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest HTC device at writing this (November 2010) is the HTC Mozart. That's the device that is equivalent to the developer phone, however they are extremely over priced (atleast in the UK) on ebay right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for results that will be exactly what other windows mobile 7 users see would be to get a Samsung Omnia 7 which you can get for about £500 from http://www.inkino.co.uk/zen/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=4186&zenid=5j8upvperu5th8j52qp7fdp945.

It's a pretty steep cost but it will give you the best results for what your app will actually be like and for any performance issues the hardware might have

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure what you mean by this. [The development tools](http://create.msdn.com) are free to download online.
A windows phone will be available from you local mobile phone shop.

Comment: I don't mean the tools.  I mean a piece of hardware where I don't have to renew a cell phone contract.

Answer (score -1):

I'd imagine you could just buy a Windows Phone 7 on contract from a phone network operator.

Alternatively, you can run a simulator on your PC. This would do for most of your development needs. The simulator is available for a free download off the Windows 7 Phone website.

Comment: I have the tools and simulator.  Wanted to get the hardware without renewing a cell phone contract.